# Creating keyspace on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra, I [wrote a blog in French that narrate all the unpleasant experiences that I have because of him](https://carlagoeshacking.wordpress.com/2017/11/14/cassandra/) (like always having `Unable to find java executable` when launching it after rebooting or the 7199 always already in use...). I created a github repository to share my cassandra directory.

But until now I can manage them unti this new one that didn't appeared last time I tried to launch Cassandra.

I try to create a keyspace about Cassandra with the help of the tutorialspoint tutorial but there is a problem: When I make the command to create a Keyspace:

```
;CREATE KEYSPACE k1 WITH
    strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy'
    AND trategy_otpions:replication_factor = '1';
    ...
```

Or even :

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE k1 WITH
   ... replication = {'class': 'strategy_class = 'SimpleStrategy'
   ... AND trategy_otpions:replication_factor = '1';
   ...
```

It just won't compile even after a semicolon ...

Do you have an idea ?

Do you have a good tutorial on Cassandra ?

#### Edit 28/11

I don't know why but this command worked :

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS k1 WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'} AND durable_writes = true;
```

---

My next question will be on how to import [a very large csv file one can found on the open platform of French public data](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/produits-alimentaires-ingredients-nutrition-labels/) there is at least 150 column which can all have the vartext type but the first one which is numeric.

Comment: Please provide the exact error messages that you receive after execution of these commands... It could be that `k1` keyspace already exists

Comment: @AlexOtt There wasn't any error message, only those `...` until I CTRL+C it

Comment: you were missing a closing bracket in 2nd attempt. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your syntax for cqlsh it's wrong, if the one that you pasted is the one that you used.

The correct syntax for cqlsh is `CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};`.

For importing data from a csv file you should read on this https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertCopyCSV.html